# Google analytics management API not returning some rows while it returns other with value 0

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a python script which asks the [management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports) for an unsampled report with the following parameters:

```
'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
'dimensions': 'ga:minute, ga:hour, ga:date',
'filters': ''
```

Its returning something as follows:

```
01/01/2016  1:00    2
01/01/2016  1:01    0
-- (GAP)
01/01/2016  1:05    5
01/01/2016  1:06    1
-- (GAP)
01/01/2016  1:09    0
01/01/2016  1:10    0
```

What's the meaning of the 0's and the gaps? Is GA not working in the times where there are gaps? Is my site not working? There are times where the gap is more than a 2 hours frame.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you specify the query as:

`'dimensions': 'ga:minute, ga:hour, ga:date',`

You can see from the result set that it returns the date first and in this case the hour last. the `0` Simply refers to midnight until 1am. This means any hits between 00:00 and 00:59 will be put into the dimension `ga:hour` as `0`. Google uses the 24 hour format so you will get hour values from `00` to `23`.

As for the gaps, If there is no data for the given time, for example if you don't see any results for `ga:hour==03` it is because Google Analytics did not receive any hits during that time and the GA API will not give you a row with 0 sessions. Since you have a dimension of `ga:minute` it can easily be that you had 0 traffic in that minute. If you are sure you have had traffic in a given timeframe but the API shows nothing, it might be your tracking code having problems.

You might want to use [Google Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to test your queries and to see in what format they will come back (i.e. which dimension is which column index).

Comment: The result set is as follows:

00,03,20160120,1
00,03,20160121,0
00,03,20160122,0
00,03,20160125,1
00,03,20160126,1
00,03,20160127,1

The one I posted in the questions was after a little procesing.

Comment: The answer is still the same, `00` refers to the hour between midnight and 1 am and will climb to `23` for 11pm to midnight. Google Analytics uses the 24 hour format. As far as the gaps are concerned, GA will not give you a row with 0 sessions. It will simply omit the hour in this case.

Comment: I have some minutes where the sesion count is 0: 

12,06,20160225,2
12,06,20160226,3
12,06,20160227,1
12,06,20160228,0
12,06,20160229,1
12,06,20160301,1
12,06,20160302,2
12,06,20160303,2
12,06,20160304,2
12,06,20160305,0

The gaps (no row returned for some minutes) means the same, that there was no traffic at that time as it returned the row with sessions count 0?

Comment: If it returns 0 as a session count that means that there was SOMETHING there that minute while a gap means that GA didn't record anything. If you have filters set on your view, GA might return 0 sessions because 0 sessions were valid for the filter but there was data for that time. Try querying other metrics such as `ga:pageviews` and `ga:totalEvents`, `ga:transactions` (if you are tracking eCommerce) and look specifically at those times where you get 0 as a session count.